# Destructuring object returned by inline function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need condition while doing destructuring, so I just created this as a function and it works.

```js
const demo = () => {
  if (2 > 1) {
    return {
      a: 'aaa',
      b: 'bbb',
    }
  }
  return {
      a: 'xxx',
      b: 'yyy',
  }
}

const { a, b } = demo()

console.log([a, b]) // will be ['aaa', 'bbb']
```

But before that I tried to do this as inline function (because I need this logic in single place so I do not see point of making this as named function), without success.

```js
const { a, b } = () => {
  if (2 > 1) {
    return {
      a: 'aaa',
      b: 'bbb',
    }
  }
  return {
      a: 'xxx',
      b: 'yyy',
  }
}

console.log([a, b]) // will be [undefined, undefined]
```

I know that this does not work because function is not executed - it's trying to destruct from function code and not function result.

But how to do it then?

In this example I could use ternary operator instead function, but in real code my function is more complicated with a lot of conditions etc so it's not possible.

```js
const { a, b } = 2 > 1 ? {
  a: 'aaa',
  b: 'bbb',
} : {
  a: 'xxx',
  b: 'yyy',
}


console.log([a, b]) // will be ['aaa', 'bbb']
```

Comment: To create and call a function, add `()` after the function expression: `const { a, b } = (() => { /*...*/ })();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute function like this:

```js
const { a, b } = (() => {
  if (2 > 1) {
    return {
      a: 'aaa',
      b: 'bbb',
    }
  }
  return {
      a: 'xxx',
      b: 'yyy',
  }
})();

console.log([a, b]) // will be ["aaa", "bbb"]
```

Comment: So simple, thank you. I was trying to add `()` at the end and this was causing errors, but O forgot about parentheses between ;)

Comment: I would also recommend this answer.